# Can't display a list into panel although that it have a layout

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2, panel

Hi StackOverFlow Community,

Well, maybe is theory that I forget read, but I don't stand why this code below don't show me anything. (I already try with another answers in the forum like config height manual and layout fit work but with these layout I can't do what I want).

Code:

```
Ext.define('myMoney.view.Settings',{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel', //--> Ext.Container don't work either
    fullscreen: true,
    xtype: 'configuracion',

    config: {
        title: 'Configuracion',
        iconCls: 'settings',
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        defaults: {
            width: '50%',
            height: '50%',
            flex:1,
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: '{item}',

                data: [
                    {item: 'Cuentas Actuales'},
                    {item: 'Agregar nueva Cuenta'},
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

The real code have two 'fieldset' before the list but I don't want show you guys a code too long. so, anyone knows what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is fixed by  **layout: 'fit'** setting. You could add it to the outer fieldset config.

Comment: well, like I do is make a overlay panel, in the controller I do this: showAccount: function(button, id){
  showAccount = Ext.Viewport.add({
   xtype: 'panel',
   layout: 'fit',
   scrollable: true,
   hideOnMaskTap: true,
   modal: true,
   centered: true,
   width: '20%',
   height: '80%',
   styleHtmlCls: true,
    items:[
     {
      xtype: 'list',
      store: 'Clasificacion',
      itemTpl: '{name}'
     }
    ]
  });
 },